# How to set the bounds in Syncfusion React PDF View using annotation

Tags: .net-core, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, pdf-viewer, ej2-syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion React PDF viewer and am performing OCR using Azure Cognitive Service.

When the user searches in the PDF file, the Azure services will return the bounds. Using these bounds, I need to highlight the text in the PDF file.
I have shared below the response I get from the Azure Cognitive Services.

How can I highlight the text in my PDF file using these bounds?

```
  {
    "docs": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "fileName": "sample.pdf",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "box": "0 0 1224 1584",
                    "words": [
                        {
                            "id": 42,
                            "text": "patient",
                            "box": "366 156 403 169"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 1258,
                            "text": "Patient",
                            "box": "35 1373 83 1386"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "box": "0 0 1224 1584",
                    "words": [
                        {
                            "id": 11,
                            "text": "Patient:",
                            "box": "98 124 179 146"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: @Sampath  var xVal = 279
    var yVal = 307.5
    var widthVal = 45
    var heightVal = 30

    viewer.annotation.addAnnotation("Highlight", {
      bounds: [{ x: xVal, y: yVal, width: widthVal, height: heightVal }],
      pageNumber: 0,
    }
    );

Comment: can you add the full code /Doc based code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can able to set bounds in the pdf viewer. Here I have given below the code snippet. Here 1.5 is calculated using the below formula.

page ratio = Azure cognitive page size width or height / PDF Viewer page size width or height

from the above am getting a page ratio = 1.5, then am dividing the x value and y value

```
var word = '694 170 836 212';
var wordBox = word.split(' ');
var xVal = parseFloat(wordBox[0] / 1.5);
var yVal = parseFloat(wordBox[1] / 1.5);
var widthVal = parseFloat(xVal);
var heightVal = parseFloat(wordBox[3]) - yVal;
pdfViewer.annotation.addAnnotation("Highlight", {
bounds: [{ x: xVal, y: yVal, width: 90, height: 25 }],
 pageNumber: 0,
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below sample JavaScript code is for JSON data representing the words and pages you want to highlight.

The `highlightPDFFromJSON` function is used to highlight words in the PDF based on the provided JSON data. A JSON object (`jsonData`) is provided, containing information about the words to be highlighted on each page.

Use the sample function below after calling your function code.

```js
const { PDFDocument, rgb } = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const axios = require('axios');

async function downloadPDF(url, outputPath) {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    await fs.writeFile(outputPath, Buffer.from(response.data));
}

async function highlightPDFFromJSON(inputPath, outputPath, jsonData) {
    try {
        // Read the existing PDF
        const pdfBytes = await fs.readFile(inputPath);

        // Load the PDF
        const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);

        // Loop through each page in the JSON data
        for (const pageData of jsonData.docs[0].pages) {
            const page = pdfDoc.getPages()[pageData.id];

            // Loop through words on the page and highlight their boxes
            for (const word of pageData.words) {
                const box = word.box.split(' ').map(parseFloat); // Parse box coordinates

                // Draw rectangle for word highlight
                page.drawRectangle({
                    x: box[0],
                    y: box[1],
                    width: box[2] - box[0],
                    height: box[3] - box[1],
                    color: rgb(1, 1, 0), // Yellow color for highlight
                    opacity: 0.5, // 50% opacity
                    borderColor: rgb(0, 0, 0), // Black border
                    borderWidth: 0.5, // Border width
                });
            }
        }

        // Save the modified PDF
        const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

        // Write the modified PDF to a new file
        await fs.writeFile(outputPath, modifiedPdfBytes);

        console.log('PDF with highlight annotations saved successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

// Example usage
const url = ' ';
const inputPath = 'Document1.pdf'; // Path to save the downloaded PDF file
const outputPath = 'output.pdf'; // Path to save the output PDF file
const jsonData = {
    "docs": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "fileName": "sample.pdf",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "box": "0 0 1224 1584",
                    "words": [
                        {
                            "id": 42,
                            "text": "patient",
                            "box": "366 156 403 169"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 1258,
                            "text": "Patient",
                            "box": "35 1373 83 1386"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "box": "0 0 1224 1584",
                    "words": [
                        {
                            "id": 11,
                            "text": "Patient:",
                            "box": "98 124 179 146"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

downloadPDF(url, inputPath)
    .then(() => highlightPDFFromJSON(inputPath, outputPath, jsonData))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error));
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I have also achieved and can set the bounds in PDF viewer using some calculations. I have posted what I have got.